# Extracting Column names from 'th' in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to iterate through some BeautifulSoup Data and get headers from the table header elements () and place them into a list. Currently, my code is extracting more than the just the header element, and is pulling part of the BS4 tags.

See attached image (result1) for current results.
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obwxs.png)

Code:

```
column_names = []

def extract_column_from_header(row):
    if (row.br):
        row.br.extract()
    if row.a:
        row.a.extract()
    if row.sup:
        row.sup.extract()
    
    column_name = ' '.join(row.contents)

    if not(column_name.strip().isdigit()):
        column_name = column_name.strip()
        return column_name    

soup=first_launch_table.find_all('th')
for i in soup:
    name=extract_column_from_header(i) 
    if name != None and len(name) > 0:
        column_names.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question needs improvement (HTML, expected result, ...), so this is only pointing in a direction - You could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select all `th` in `table`, extract content with `.text` while iterating with `list comprehension`:

```
[th.text for th in soup.select('table th')]
```

Or based on your example:

```
[th.text for th in first_launch_table.find_all('th')]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly, the data is in html, pulled form wikipedia and parsed through beautiful soup. My goal was to parse it directly into a list with header text as the list items. 
The list would consist of items like "Payload mass", "orbit", and "customer", and the bs4 tags would be omitted. I'll read up on css selectors.